# What are the iOS supported SSL/TLS versions and ciphers?

Tags: ios, security, ssl, encryption

I am developing an iPhone application, I am trying to find a list of supported SSL/TLS versions and ciphers for iOS.  Is there a reference or a method I can call to get this answer?  Also, if I can limit the supported protocols and ciphers via code, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The TLS functionality in iOS is provided by [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org), so look at their compatibility list.  As far as limiting "the supported protocols and ciphers via code" goes, remember that you're working in a sandbox so you can only do that for your own app. You can't, for example, force every other app on the phone into plaintext. You'd present the list of ciphers you're willing to use during the negotiation phase of the SSL connection.